# How to put text into the tabs - Zen Coding

Tags: html, emmet

With `ul>li*3` I achieve

```
            <ul>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
            <ul>
                <li>Value</li>
                <li>Value</li>
                <li>Value</li>
            </ul>
```

How can I make it using Zen Coding? And one more thing - can I list different Values so that it becomes like this:

```
            <ul>
                <li>Value</li>
                <li>Another Value</li>
                <li>Last Value</li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this abbreviation for the first case: `ul>li{Value}*3` — you can use the curly braces for inserting the text into elements.

However, to do the second case you could only do this: `ul>li{Value}+li{Another Value}+li{Last Value}`, right now there is no way to list only the values for multiple elements.

However, if the only thing that would be different is a number (like in Joonas' example), you can still achieve it easily: `ul>li{Line $}*3` — you can use `$` in attributes or text nodes of abbreviations when using multipliers and they would transform to the element's counter.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean, but you can write:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

...and after that, you should first select these lines and then use *'wrap with abbreviation'* with this zencode: `ul>li*`, which will produce this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

---

Zen coding wiki:

http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/wiki/Actions#Wrap_with_Abbreviation